# RegEx to substitute tag names, leaving the content and attributes intact

Tags: html, regex, sublimetext3

I would like to replace opening and closing tag, leaving the content of tags and its attribute intact.

Here is what I have:

```
<div class="QText">Text to be kept</div>
```

to be replaced with

```
<span class="QText">Text to be kept</span>
```

I tried this expression which finds all expressions I want but there seems to be no way to replace found expressions.

```
<div class="QText">(.*?)</div>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If its going to be literal like that, capture what's to be kept, then replace the rest, i.e. Find `<div( class="QText">.*?</)div>` replace `<span$1span>`

Comment: @sln, can you post it as the answer - it works like a charm!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posted as requested

If its going to be literal like that, capture what's to be kept, then replace the rest,

Find:  `<div( class="QText">.*?</)div>`
Replace: `<span$1span>`

Answer (score 2):

Just replace div.

```
var s="<div class='QText'>Text to be kept</div>";
alert(s.replace(/div/g,"span"));
```

Demo: <kbd>http://jsfiddle.net/9sgvP/</kbd>

Mark it as answer if it helps ;)

Comment: Well, you're using JS, the question was to use Find/Replace+RegEx. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @Alexander you'll have to use js even if you want to use regex

Comment: Well, Sln's reply above answers the questions perfectly.

Comment: @Alexander, why do you think regex is a separate thing? Its part of javascript

Comment: because for the task I posted, Regex suits perfectly; the task was a simple Find/Replace job. Why do we need JS for that?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49769/discussion-between-alexander-and-amit-joki)

Answer (score 2):

I think @AmitJoki's answer will work well enough in certain circumstances, but if you only want to replace `div` elements when they have an attribute or a specific set of attributes, then you would want to use a regex replacement with backreferences - how you specify and refer to a backreference, unfortunately, depends upon your chosen editor. Visual Studio has the most unique and annoying "flavor" of regex I know of, while Dreamweaver has a fairly typical implementation (both as well as I imagine whatever editor you're using do regex replacement - you just have to know the menu item or keystroke to bring up the dialog).

If memory serves, Dreamweaver has replacement options when you hit Ctrl+F, while you have to hit Ctrl+H, so try those.

Once you get a "Find" and "Replace" box, you would put something like what you have in your last example above: `<div class="QText">(.*?)</div>` or perhaps `<div class="(QText|RText|SText)">(.*?)</div>` into your "Find" box, then put something like `<span class="QText">\1</span>` or `<span class="\1">\2</span>` in the "Replacement" box. A few utilities might use `$1` to refer to a backreference rather than `\1`, but you'll have to lookup help or experiment to be sure.

If you are using a language to run this expression, you need to tell us which language.

If you are using a specific editor to run this expression, you need to tell us which editor.

...and never forget the prevailing wisdom on [regex and HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: this worked extremely well `<div( class="QText">.*?</)div> replace <span$1span>` Thanks you! Using SublimeText 3

Comment: I see - you used a different answer than one that I provided. it looks like @sln posted his answer. good luck in your future endeavors!